# SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'L'.")

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a query as follows and running into  error shown below,please suggest how to overcome this?

```
SELECT 
    pr.PromoteBuildId, pr.BuildStatus,
    pr.PromoteBuildConfigId, pr.BuildLocation,
    pr.PromoteBuildChangeList, pr.TestResults,
    pr.TestStatus, pr.TestUrl, pr.ArtifactsLocation 
FROM 
    packagewarehouse.PromoteBuilds pr
JOIN  
    packagewarehouse.WarehousePromoteBuildConfigurations w ON pr.PromoteBuildConfigId = w.PromoteBuildConfigId 
WHERE
    w.WarehouseId = 47914L;
```

Error:

> [SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'L'.")

Comment: you got an L in 47914L what's that?

Comment: Luis - WarehouseId is BIGINT NOT NULL and 47914L is an accepted value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "L" from the literal `w.WarehouseId = 47914L`.  You don't need to try to coerce the data type in SQL.